# Create text-area dotted on each line

Tags: html, css, textarea, border

I would like to make a contactform like this one: http://line25.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/letter-form/20.jpg (a multi-line textarea where each line has a dotted border-bottom, like a notebook. So not just the bottom border of the field)

The *name* and *e-mail* fields I already have:

```
#contactform input[type="text"]{
   border: none;
   border-bottom: dashed 2px #c9c9c9;
   width: 200px;
}
```

but I seem unable to fix the *message* part...? I thought it would be a textarea with some styling but I don't seem to get the right effect... Is it even possible to style each line separatly?

Thank you!

Comment: Use Background image for text area, there is no other way you can do it.

Comment: `message` may be a `<textarea>`, not an `<input>`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `textarea` use an dot image as background.

```
#contactform textarea {
    background: url("dot-bg.png");
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but if I want the dots on every line of my textarea...?

Comment: And you create a background like a line! and just repeat it! :)

Comment: I think I'll gice this one a try indeed! :)

Answer (score -1):

only add this

```
 <input type="text" class="field-name" value=""/>

 <textarea class="field-message"></textarea>

   input[type="text"].field-name{
   border-bottom: dashed 2px #c9c9c9;
   width: 300px;
   }

   textarea.field-message{
   border-bottom: dashed 2px #c9c9c9;
   width: 300px;
   resize:none;
   }
```

No use images, the size of the webpage is more.

Comment: Doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Personaly I think it's not very user-friendly if the user can't read the whole message he wrote...?

Answer (score -2):

You can add a div instead of textarea and add multiple input tags in it. Working JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/n16vrqda/ try this

```css
label{
      margin-right: 22px;
}

.message{
    float: left;
  margin-top: 10px;
      margin-right: 10px;
}

input[type="text"].field-name{
    border:none;
   border-bottom: dotted 2px #c9c9c9;
   width: 300px;
    margin:10px;
   }

   .field-message{
       float:left;
   }
```

```html
<label>Name : </label>
<input type="text" class="field-name" value=""/><br>
<label>Email : </label>
<input type="text" class="field-name" value=""/><br>
<div>
    <label class="message">Message : </label>
    <div class="field-message">
        <input type="text" class="field-name" value=""/><br>
        <input type="text" class="field-name" value=""/><br>
        <input type="text" class="field-name" value=""/><br>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This looks like the answer I'm looking for, but can I let these answers be sent to my e-mail in a correct way? With the multiple text-inputs?

Comment: @user1946390 What do you mean by "sent to my e-mail"?

Comment: This will be a contact form so I would like to recieve the results.