# css- How to add dotted line beneath input?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to accomplish a dotted line like below:

[image]

And so far I have gotten this far:

[image]

I am not too sure how to I replicate like the first image so that I can write text on it. How do I do that?

Code:

```
  <div class="card-body">
      <div class="row mb-4">

      <div class="col-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 font-style" style="font-size:15px;">
      <h6 class="mb-3">Receiver:</h6>
      <div>
      Bill Gates
      </div>
      <br> <br>
      <div>Attention To:</div>
      <div>Contact No:</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 font-style" style="font-size:15px;">
      <h6 class="mb-3">Deliver To:</h6>
       <div>23, Jalan Sepupu Masam</div>
        <div>Taman Megah</div>
        <div>Kuala Lumpur</div> 
      <div>Attention To:</div>
      <div>Contact No:</div>
      </div>
```

I am using simple bootstrap to align my texts. I also need to add a "square box" to wrap it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create text-area dotted on each line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30485528/create-text-area-dotted-on-each-line)

Comment: No, because it does not allow me to create the line rather than using a background picture?

Answer (score 2):

This may help you get going:

```css
#main {
  height: 20px;
  width: 500px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.dottedLines {
  border-bottom: thin black dotted;
  margin: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="divName">
    Name:
    <div class="dottedLines">

    </div>
    <div class="dottedLines">

    </div>
    <div class="dottedLines">Bill Gates.

    </div>
    <div class="dottedLines">

    </div>
    <div class="dottedLines">

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

To add border:

```css
#MainBorder {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
}

#main {
  height: 20px;
  width: 500px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.dottedLines {
  border-bottom: thin red dotted;
  margin: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="MainBorder">
  <div id="main">
    <div id="divName">Name:
      <div class="dottedLines"></div>
      <div class="dottedLines"></div>
      <div class="dottedLines">Bill Gates.</div>
      <div class="dottedLines"></div>
      <div class="dottedLines"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: So I don't need to use this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30485528/create-text-area-dotted-on-each-line

Comment: Not needed, it depends on how many lines you need and create those `div`s and you will be ready to add text!

Comment: If in-case if you need `thick` lines then kindly change from `thin` to `thick` for the size that should help you.

Comment: Would it be possible to add box around it like in the 1st pic?

Comment: @LordJesus I just added the snippet as well, you need to create a `div` kind of outer and add `height` and `width` to it.

Comment: It is better to do this using `table` since if I need to fetch data from db, it would be easier to populate?

Comment: Yeah it is your call, you can do it any way, the concept remains same to handle the border, instead of div use `td` there that's it.

Comment: Would you mind accepting it as answer and voting if you think worth doing it?